# How can I condense this code?

Tags: jquery, html

Edit - sorry this was very unclear. I want to place the id into the src for multiple hover events.

```
$("#trig1").hover(
  function () { 
    $("#main").attr("src", "trig1.png");
  }, 
  function () {
    $("#main").attr("src", "4.png");
  }
);

$("#trig2").hover(
  function () {
    $("#main").attr("src", "trig2.png");
  }, 
  function () {
    $("#main").attr("src", "4.png");
  }
);

$("#trig3").hover(
  function () {
    $("#main").attr("src", "trig3.png");
  }, 
  function () {
    $("#main").attr("src", "4.png");
  }
);

html

<area id="trig1 2 3 etc.." shape="poly" alt="blah" coords="0,1,2,3,4,...">
<img src="4.png">
```

I've been trying something like

```
$('area').each(function(e)
   {
    $(this).hover(
        function () { 
        $(e).attr("src", $(e).attr("id") + ".png"});
    }, 
    function () {
        $("#main").attr("src", "4.png");
    });
```

This doesn't work but I don't really understand what I'm doing with regards to function(e). Is there a decent place to read up on this?

Comment: Can you post your html please?

Comment: You can read out from here http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/01/working-with-jquery-13-new-event-object.html

Comment: What is `$('area')` ?  Seems like a typo for a class or an Id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#trig1, #trig2, #trig3').hover(
  function () { $('#main').attr('src', this.id.substr(-1) + '.png'); }, 
  function () { $("#main").attr('src', '4.png'); }
);
```

Comment: Hehe. :) I agree with you though that this is rather fragile and there are better ways to do that. I might go with `data` attributes in the `#trig` elements and use classes instead of hardcoded ids, for instance. Or better naming conventions like `this.id + '_hover.png'` or something along those lines.

Comment: Ah nice one, this makes sense to me. Thanks guys.

Comment: @deceze yeah, I think `data` attributes are the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're setting `src` attributes to `trig1`, `trig2` and `trig3` instead of your `.png`s.

Try:

```
$(e).attr("src", ($(e).attr("id").charAt(4) + ".png") });
```

**Note this is a very fragile implementation but you get the idea and probably can figure out a better (regex based?) one.**